# OSX - After using controlTextDidEndEditing:notification , how do I get focus

Tags: macos, nstextfield, nscollectionview

I want to be able to edit some NSTextFields that are bound in an NSCollectionView. I'm getting notified through `controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification` and I can edit fields within one record.

However, when I want to edit another record, I don't have focus of any field. How do I relinquish control of the first record, to be able to edit a second?

I'm using a switch on `controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)notification` to identify each field in a record through hard-coded tags in IB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

my fault. forgot to release First Responder.